# Proper string conversion with implicit data type in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have arbitrary strings that shall be converted to suited data types (i.e. scalar double, double array or string), depending on their content.
`str2num()` does its job when interpreting the `status` return value, but the function itself evaluates the content of the string which:

1. causes `str2num('3-7')` to be `-4 (double)`, but I want to stick to `'3-7' (char array)`
2. is a severe security issue, since it can potentially execute any code

One workaround is to use `str2double()`, which does not end up with double arrays, but just scalars or strings. Unfortunately, `isstrprop()` is not really appropriate for this.

Example inputs (and outputs):

- '123.4' -> 123.4 (double scalar) [covered by `str2double()` and `str2num()`]
- abc' -> 'abc' (char array) [inherently covered by `str2double()` and `str2num()`]
- '123,456' -> [123, 456] (double array) [covered by `str2num()` only]
- '3-7' -> '3-7' (char array) [don't know how to cover]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (thanks to @user2999345):

```
function res = str2impl(str, delimiter)
narginchk(1,2);
if isempty(str)
    res = [];
    return
end
if nargin < 2
    delimiter = ',';
end
splits = strsplit(str, delimiter);
res = str2double(splits);
if any(isnan(res)) & ~strcmpi(str, 'NaN') % NaN not specifically requested
    res = str;
end
```

ends up in

```
C = {'123.4','abc','123,456','3-7','NaN','',[]};
for ii = 1:numel(C)
  r{ii,1} = str2impl(C{ii});
end
disp(r)

[  123.4000]
'abc'
[1×2 double]
'3-7'
[       NaN]
[]
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

use `str2double` and `strsplit`:

```
C = {'123.4','abc','123,456','3-7'};
for ii = 1:numel(C)
    CC = strsplit(C{ii},',');
    res = [str2double(CC)];
    if isnan(res)
        res = C{ii};
    end
    disp(res)
    disp(class(res))
    disp('****************')
end
```

shows:

```
123.4000
double
****************
abc
char
****************
123   456
double
****************
3-7
char
****************
```

Comment: nice :) like that a lot! Thanks!

Comment: @braggPeaks This doesn't meet the criteria that you mentioned in the [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43275999/proper-string-data-type-conversion-in-matlab?noredirect=1#comment73622509_43275999). You've stated that `NaN` is a valid numeric value.

Comment: @SardarUsama You are right but this one is easy to catch, no? Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: @SardarUsama he didn't need to read the comments in order to give the proper answer to my Q. Doing an additional `strcmpi('NaN')` is a task I can accomplish. Obviously you got a better solution if `NaN` really makes the difference for you?

Comment: @braggPeaks It doesn't make any difference to me. You stated that it made difference to you. If you already could do that, why did you ask? From your above comment, it seems that you need to read the documentation of `strcmpi` because that's not how it works. Read your comment and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you ask more questions.

Comment: @SardarUsama Your comment tells me that you still did not understand this Q and that's why I understand you cannot be of help here (I was not able to do it w/o the proper answer of @user2999345). I agree that Q's should be written that everybody can understand, although this might be difficult for some cases. Sticking to an off-topic issue like `NaN` is wasting not only your time.

Comment: @braggPeaks You brought the off-topic issue in the comment that you have shamelessly deleted now where you showed that it was a matter of concern for you!

Comment: @SardarUsama Happy to see that you are also shamelessly deleting comments ;) Cleaned up and posted solution, maybe it better helps you to understand the Q now. Cheers.

Comment: @braggPeaks Point out the deleted comment that creates the confusion. Please familiarize yourself with SO standards according to which answers are not meant to be posted in the question.

Comment: @SardarUsama I did (for your convenience): `... & ~strcmpi(str, 'NaN') % NaN not specifically requested`